# problem in running react-native app on emulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

when i try to run react native app made by react-native cli on my android emulator and i get the error below(im using npx reract-native run-android)

```
BUILD FAILED in 3s
error Failed to build the app.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat build -x lint -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at makeError (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)        
    at module.exports.sync (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at build (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\buildAndroid\index.js:83:22)
    at runOnSpecificDevice (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:151:33)
    at buildAndRun (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:120:12)
    at Object.runAndroid [as func] (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:69:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\work\dronedetail\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```